Oligomerisation of L-Lactic acid to Prepolymer
I am working on my Thesis in which i synthesised PLA out of L-lactic acid. I am using the Methods from a research paper from the HEIA-FR which i linked here aswell.
Method and Paper that I used
The second step is to perform a polymerisation of pure lactic acid to a prepolymer of PLA. I have done this and know what the educt aswell as product formulas are, but I don't know what happens in terms of a chemical process during the polymerisation.
Simply put, I need someone to explain to me what happens to the lactic acid molecule durng the polymerisation so that it turns into the prepolymer.
Thank you very much for your help!

It is not clear what you mean by the "prepolymer", as I understand it there is a cyclic dilactone which is formed by lactic acid reacting with itself. To form this from lactic acid you need two molecules of lactic acid, this will then react to form the cyclic dimer and two molecules of water.
The reaction of lactic acid to form polylactic acid is normally a condensation polymerisation, there will be different length oligomers in the reaction mixture. It is similar to the formation of nylon 6,6 or polyester from benzene-1,4-dicarboxylic acid and ethylene glycol.
I also see a parallel with the formation of plastic sulfur when normal sulfur (S8) is melted. What happens there is that a S-S bond breaks in the S8 to form a diradical. This can then react with other diradicals to form very long chains in a reversable reaction.
In the case of lactic acid then the normal reaction to form the polymer will be a Fisher ester synthesis from the carboxylic acid and the alcohol groups. This will require a cataylst, the normal cataylst is either a Bronsted acid or a Lewis acid. I know that it is possible to digest down waste polylactic acid with methanol under mild conditions using a gentle Lewis acid such as zinc chloride to form methyl lactate.

If you look at the linked paper, the prepolymer is a linear oligomer with DP of 8-12. The lactide is formed in the second step.
